# custom attributes are not working for themes in android

Tags: android

In my `attr.xml`, I have defined `descriptor_bg` like:

```
</declare-styleable>    
    <attr name="descriptor_bg" format="reference|color" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

and in `style.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme_blue">
    <item name="descriptor_bg">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I have used above attribute like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:angle="90" />
<solid android:color="@attr/descriptor_bg"/>
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/blue_stroke_bg" />
```

But I am getting an exception like:

`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/descriptor_bg.xml`

from drawable resource ID #0x7f020006

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
File res/drawable-mdpi/descriptor_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020006
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct syntax is **?attr/descriptor_bg**.

Unfortunately this probably won't fix your issue, because theme attributes aren't supported in XML drawables. This was [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251) in L-preview release though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to stick to a single format identifier, like:

```
<attr name="descriptor_bg" format="color" />
```

It should automatically translate the color from RGB value or reference.

Comment: Thanks Waqas, I have tried with single format but getting same exception.

Comment: I think the problem may also exist here `<solid android:color="@attr/descriptor_bg"/>`. Instead of passing **attr** reference, try setting the color reference **@android:color/black**